# Surveying questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Surveying can be a big part of civil engineering. Most of us have probably had to take a surveying class in college, but it isn't "Engineering" in a strict sense, and can be a separate field. A quick browse through the list of current SE sites doesn't reveal any obvious place to ask a surveying question.

I'm thinking about questions pertaining to:

Distance/angle/elevation measurement with surveying equipment

Questions about surveying equipment (total stations, gps, etc.)

Surveying techniques and best practices.

However, I think we should draw the line at strictly geometrical or mathematical questions.

Should surveying be considered on-topic?

Edit: I realize now my question wasn't very clear. I want surveying to be on topic, but a purlry math based question should go to the math SE.

Comment: Why do you think we should draw the line?  What are the negative consequences of making surveying questions on topic since they are such a large part of civil engineering?

Comment: Im pro surveying questions. I realize my stance wasnt clear there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6/our-scope-and-overlaps-with-sister-sites.  Although I'm too cowardly to actually cast a close vote as such.  :-)

Answer (score 14):

Given that surveying is part of Civil Engineering, I would vote to allow those types of questions.

Later on, if we find the site's scope is *too* broad, then we can narrow the scope down.  But until then, we ought to welcome high quality, engineering related questions.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your edit- I think I see your point. When it comes to questions about surveying, there are those that deal with the act of surveying and interpreting those results; and potentially those more rooted in fundamental geometry.

In a way this meta-question follows what's going on with the following question, where it's (arguably) much more a problem of statistics than engineering: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136/principal-component-regression-with-an-additional-factor

Although, as GlenH7 says, and is coming out of the discussion about our scope, I think we should be very weary of pre-emptively turning down questions based on their fields.

Comment: n.b. as a civil engineer; I think that surveying is _very much_ part of engineering!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a practical "engineering" type question on surveying (or most other topics) as one that deals with actual machines and/or equipment.

Whereas a theoretical or mathematical question would deal strictly with mathematical theorems or equations, without reference to tangible objects.

Comment: There are two kinds of engineering: civil and military. Civil has many fields of specialisms such as structural, mechanical, electrical, hydrological, environmental, land surveying, and atmospheric. I vote to include surveying